# change multiple images on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 6 images.
When they are rolled over the images change using css hover. 
When the images are clicked the original image appears (again using css) but I want the rest of the images to dim when one is selected.
I've been looking into various JS option but just cant seem to get it to work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: you should post your code to show us what you've tried so far, and then people will be able to help you!

Comment: If you've looked at various options using jquery, how about posting some of the work you've already done and letting others take a look? The jquery `.click()` method would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution is adding a class to the selected image and the images parent.
This makes it easier to maintain as the styling is all done in css.

Quick example here:

css

```
.img{
    display:inline-block;
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.clicked .img{
    opacity:0.3;
}

.clicked .img.selected{
    opacity:1;
    background:red;
}
```

js

```
​
$('.img').on('click', function() {
    $('.img').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.container').addClass('clicked');
})​
```

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="img">img</div>
    <div class="img">img</div>
    <div class="img">img</div>
    <div class="img">img</div>
    <div class="img">img</div>
    <div class="img">img</div>
</div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/renekoch/y6YCc/

Comment: If it was me, I would do it in the same way

Comment: Thanks Rene, that's what I'm after. I had the add/remove class but didn't think to add a class to the container! This script is working on JSFiddle can't seem to get it to work as a standalone page. I added the semi colon at the end of the JS but that didn't help!

Comment: Anyone any ideas on this?, still struggling to implement this outside of jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks Rene - I managed to get it to work! Appreciate your help!